# How to create many instances of vtkContourWidget

Tags: python, vtk

I want to be able to create many instances of vtkContourWidget, letting the user draw lines and manipulating the nodes, but it seems I'm not doing it right.

Here is the code:

```
import vtk

def main():

    # Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

    Interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    Interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

    style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTerrain()
    Interactor.SetInteractorStyle(style)

    Interactor.AddObserver("KeyPressEvent", keyPressEvent)

    # Render and interact
    renderWindow.Render()
    Interactor.Start()

def keyPressEvent(obj, event):

    key = obj.GetKeySym()

    if key == 'n':
        contourRep = vtk.vtkOrientedGlyphContourRepresentation()

        contourWidget = vtk.vtkContourWidget()
        contourWidget.SetInteractor(obj)
        contourWidget.SetRepresentation(contourRep)
        contourWidget.On()

        #contourWidget.SetEnabled()
        obj.Start()

    return

main()
```

It almost works fine this way, the problem is that, when I want to close the application window, I have to click the button to close the window many times. And I have to click one time for each vtkContourWidget created.

It seems that each time I call the function `keyPressEvent` and create a vtkContourWidget, the `obj.Start()` (that is the same of `Interactor.Start()`) line instantiates kind of another instance of the application?

I've also tried `contourWidget.SetEnabled()` (with `obj.Start()` commented out), and it works to create new instances of vtkContourWidget, but when I try to close the app window, the app freezes.

With both `obj.Start()` and `contourWidget.SetEnabled()` on the code, I can create many instances, but each time I create a new instance, the previous one disappears.

I think [this topic](https://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtk-developers/2008-April/020587.html) may have the solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy-pasting your code and running it with VTK 6.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 seems to work correctly. The window closes as expected using the closing button or "q".

So this seems to be a bug related to the VTK release you are using on your system.

Kind regards.

Comment: Yes, it probably is related to the VKT release. I was using VTK 6.3 that comes with Anaconde 2 (Python 2.7). Porting my code to VTK 8.1 in C++ solved the issue. Thanks!